# Linq Subquery with Group by

Tags: linq

I have the following query which works fine:

```
 var results = (from p in db.globalMap
                               where p.LId == 1
                               group p by p.GroupId into g
                               select new
                               {
                                   GroupId = g.Key,
                                   client = g.Select(k => k.ClientId).FirstOrDefault(),                                       
                                   cnt = g.Count()
                               }).ToList();
```

What I like to do is query another table to get the clientname based on the ClientId.

I tried something like but get red swiggly lines. Wondering how I can do a subquery like the way I want to below.

```
     var results = (from p in db.globalMap
                               where p.LId == 1
                               group p by p.GroupId into g
                               select new
                               {
                                   GroupId = g.Key,
                                   clientName =  (select x in db.client where x.clientId = clientId select x.clientName).FirstOrDefault(),                                       
                                   cnt = g.Count()
                               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my answer? Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it similarily how you did the first one:-

```
var results = (from p in db.globalMap
               where p.LId == 1
               group p by p.GroupId into g
               select new
               {
                   GroupId = g.Key,
                   clientName =  db.client.Where(x => x.clientId == clientId)
                                          .Select(x => x.clientName).FirstOrDefault(),
                   cnt = g.Count()
               }).ToList();
```